# How does Empowered Spell work?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, sorcerer, metamagic

I'm using a non-official translated version (there is no official one for my language) of the 5e PHB, and checking it with the official one makes me confused.

> When you roll damage for a spell, you can spend 1 sorcery point to reroll a number of the damage dice up to your Charisma modifier (minimum of one). You must use the new rolls.

In a practical way, how does it work?

Can I reroll the number of dice up to my Charisma modifier, or only the dice which are lower than my charisma modifier?

**Building a scenario**
I have a Cha MOD of 5.
I have the following roll:

3d6: 1, 2, 3;
3d8: 4, 5, 7;
2d12: 6, 7;

Comment: May I ask what is your native language?

Comment: Brazilian's portuguese. My confusion was due to "dice" been used in a singular form. Making it sound like I could only change one damage dice, which the damage is equal or lesser than my charisma modifier. @T.J.L. clarified that.

Comment: It can be confusing.  Dice is one of those words that is often misused.  Historically, dice is the plural of die, but in modern standard English dice is both the singular and the plural: 'throw the dice' could mean a reference to either one or more than one dice. and.dice.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**[Empowered Spell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/sorcerer#EmpoweredSpell)** allows you to reroll a number of dice; it does not make any specification on the value of the dice.

> When you roll damage for a spell, you can spend 1 sorcery point to reroll a number of the damage dice up to your Charisma modifier (minimum of one). You must use the new rolls.

Compare to **[Great Weapon Fighting](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/fighter#GreatWeaponFighting)**, which explicitly calls out the values you get to reroll.

> When you roll a 1 or 2 on a damage die for an attack you make with a melee weapon that you are wielding with two hands, you can reroll the die and must use the new roll, even if the new roll is a 1 or a 2.

Answer (score 8):

"a number of the damage dice up to your Charisma modifier (minimum of one)" means up to that number of dice.

For your modifier of +5 you can reroll up to 5 dice. This is capped by either the number of dice rolled (e.g. if the damage is 3d8, you can only reroll up to 3) and your choice of which ones to roll (e.g. if you roll a 1, 7 & 5, you would definitely reroll the 1 since you can't do worse, you would probably keep the 7 since you are unlikely to do as well and the 5 is a 50-50 call).

Answer (score 5):

The limit is on how many dice you can pick up and roll again. What number you rolled on them the first time does not matter.